# OpenDKIM query timed out (even with opendkim-testkey and Nameservers set)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, postfix, dkim, opendkim

I try to set up a mail server on Debian with opendkim and opendmarc

When I receive an email, SpamAssassin refuse it because opendkim can't do the DNS query

I tested with opendkim-testkey command, the DNS query is timed out :

```
$ opendkim-testkey -s 20161025 -d gmail.com -vvv
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key '20161025._domainkey.gmail.com'
opendkim-testkey: '20161025._domainkey.gmail.com' query timed out
```

I tried to do the DNS query with dig on the server, with success

`$ dig txt 20161025._domainkey.gmail.com`

> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   20161025._domainkey.gmail.com. 282 IN   TXT     "k=rsa; p=MIIB[...]AB"

By reading other posts, I try to add a Nameservers, but it changes nothing at all

As anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved my own issue :

In /etc/opendkim.conf, I commented

```
TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key
```

My local dns server do already this job

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was a firewall issue, OpenDKIM queries DNS **root servers directly** (see **TrustAnchorFile** in /etc/opendkim.conf). Opening my firewall in outgoing direction for all IP addresses in /usr/share/dns/root.key fixed the problem.